# How to get file api image size in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
if(window.FileReader) {
    reader = new FileReader();
    var sendingcontext = sendingcanvas.getContext('2d');
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) { 
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = theFile.target.result;

    image.onload = function() {
    sendingcanvas.width=this.width;
    sendingcanvas.height= this.height;
    console.log("height: " + sendingcanvas.height + " width: " + sendingcanvas.width)
         sendingcontext.drawImage(image, 0,0);
    };
        });
        reader.onloadend = function(e){
        showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    alert(sendingcanvas.toDataURL());
}
```

I Suppose I don't have to explain what the code does, But what I want is to get the file api image height and width, set it to `sendingcanvas` and send it to server using ajax by using it's `toDataURL()`. I know This is weird but If I remove the `alert(sendingcanvas.toDataURL())` from my script My server receives an empty image but If I have it in my script In my server the image is exactly how the client have it.

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Are you really sure that you want to convert the image to a png with quality + meta info loss?

Answer (score 0):

You can try let the image in a `<img>` tag and get the real width and size of the image in case what you having a DOM:

```js
var height = $( "#main-reference" ).get( 0 ).naturalWidth;
var width = $( "#main-reference" ).get( 0 ).naturalHeight;
```

this property gives you the real height and width of the img although you have broken the img with css

Comment: Thanks for suggestion But do you know what is causing my problem there

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point out that the image you are uploading is being converted to a png (if that is what you want)
The uploaded file is no longer the same as the user selected

Btw, sending a blob is better then uploading a base64 string that is ~3x larger you can use this [polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js) to get support for [canvas.toBlob(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) in older browsers

This is basicly what you are doing:

```js
function showUploadedItem(image){
  document.body.appendChild(image)
}

// Simulate a file (image)
var black_1x1 = new Uint8Array([71,73,70,56,57,97,1,0,1,0,128,0,0,5,4,4,0,0,0,44,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,2,68,1,0,59])
var file = new Blob([black_1x1], {type:"image/gif"})

console.log(file)

var img = new Image
img.onload = function() {
  console.log("height: " + this.height + " width: " + this.width)

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  canvas.width = this.width
  canvas.height = this.height
  showUploadedItem(this)
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0)
  canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    console.log(blob)
    // Send the canvas pic to server (using fetch, xhr or jQuery
    // With or without FormData
    // fetch('/upload', {method: 'post', body: blob})
  })
}
// No need to use fileReader + base64
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

```css
/* Just to make the pixel more vissible */
body img {
  width: 10px
}
```

```html
<!-- toBlob polyfill -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/master/canvas-toBlob.js"></script>
```